# Please help me identify this insect

Tags: canada, bug-identification

I live in Edmonton, Alberta in Canada and recently noticed this insect on my bed.  It was approximately 2mm in size.

Could anyone please help me identify it and tell me how to get rid of them.  Thank you.

[image: **First picture **]
[image: Second picture]
[image: third picture]

Comment: Did you mean 2 cm?

Comment: @Weather Vane: No, it was very small. No larger than 2-3mm. I had to zoom all the way in and use the macro-shot setting on my phone.

Comment: It is unclear whether there is one insect or an infestation of, say, [bed bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_bug) although it doesn't look like one.

Comment: Definitely not bedbugs as I know them, not from the size or the shape.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a Flat Bark Beetle (*[Silvanus bidentatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvanus_bidentatus)*), which are native to North America and apart of the [*Silvanidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvanidae) family.

I would expect just a typical pesticide spray to kill them, though spraying that on your bed probably isn't a good idea.  I wouldn't take any further action unless you have a lot of them.